# Navigating buttons are not responding

Tags: android, button, navigation

I am trying develop a quiz application in android studio and face a problem with my navigation buttons...
My navigation buttons like next and back are not working, what did I missed...
below is code that i used in java class...
Please point it where I go wrong and what you suggest to correct...

```
public class MC_questions extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView tvquestions, tvanswers, tvtotallength_yy, tvpresentindex_xx;

    Button bback, bshowanswer, bnext;


    String[] mc_questions, mc_answers;

    int index;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questions);





///initialization of text view
        tvquestions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvquestions);
        tvanswers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvanswer);
        tvtotallength_yy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvyy);
        tvpresentindex_xx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvxx);

///initialization of buttons
        bback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bback);
        bshowanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bshowanswer);
        bnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnext);

///importing the string array from values folder
        mc_questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mc_questions);
        mc_answers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mc_answers);

///onclick listener for 3 buttons
        bback.setOnClickListener(this);
        bshowanswer.setOnClickListener(this);
        bnext.setOnClickListener(this);


///Setting values to our variables and 4 TextViews
        index = 0;
        tvquestions.setText(mc_questions[index]);
        tvanswers.setText("Press \"Show Answer\" Button for Answer");
        tvpresentindex_xx.setText (String.valueOf(index+1));
        tvtotallength_yy.setText(String.valueOf(mc_questions.length));



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bback:


                break;

            case R.id.bshowanswer:


                break;

            case R.id.bnext:


                break;


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside according to button click inside your onClick method

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.bback:

    //write a code here that you want to execute when this button is presssed
                    break;

                case R.id.bshowanswer:

    //write a code here that you want to execute when this button is presssed
                    break;

                case R.id.bnext:
    //write a code here that you want to execute when this button is presssed

                    break;


            }

        }
```

> My navigation buttons like next and back are not working

Because You did not put any code inside your `onClick` method

Comment: its tottaly your logic. How should I know what you want to perform on button clicks

Comment: I can just tell you that your code for buttons should go in onclick method